# I'm getting late initialization error in flutter when trying to use flutter_screenutil package with introduction_screen package

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

The late initialization error comes when I add .w, .h, .sp to double values like,

```
top: 16.h
```

or

```
right: 16.w
```

Here is the code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yN2AqKF2LOMFYkX9PzsTVz_o5hktSY0D/view?usp=sharing

These are the packages which I have installed

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: 2.1.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.0+2
  page_transition: ^2.0.4
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the ScreenUtil class just like it was provided in the example page [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil)

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     //You need to add this line to your code
    //Set the fit size (fill in the screen size of the device in the design) If the design is based on the size of the 360*690(dp)
    ScreenUtil.init(
        BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
        designSize: Size(360, 690),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        orientation: Orientation.portrait);
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```